# Differing types in declaration and definition in C++

Tags: c++

I was going through a piece of code and found a strange thing. A function was declared as follows:

```
void func(int, int*);
```

but then it was defined as

```
void func(int a, int &p) { ... }
```

The code is compiling properly in gcc under Linux. How can this be possible?(it has been build as a C file)

Comment: Overloaded functions perhaps?

Comment: It's possible because you can have multiple functions with the same name but different parameter types. You can also have a definition of a function without a declaration.

Comment: I removed the C and g++ tags. The former doesn't apply, the latter is irrelevant.

Comment: It was compiling and running properly with gcc. The declaration is different than the defination, isnt it? How come the linker found the definition of the function

Comment: @Nipun do you ever call the function outside of the compilation unit (`.cpp` file) where it is defined? If so, the declaration doesn't apply, since the linker finds the definition in the file.

Comment: "it has been build as a C file" - I doubt it. `int &p` isn't valid C. Note that if the file extension is `.C` (capitalised), then GCC will assume it's C++, not C. Use lower case `.c` for a C source file.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

// overloads, nothing to do with func(int, int&)
int func(int, int*);
int func(int, short);
int func(int, std::string);

int func(int a, int& b) {
    return a;
}

int main() {
  int x;
  std::cout << func(4, x) << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

that is, functions that take different parameters are completely different functions (even if they have the same name). Those functions are said to have a different *signature*.

Comment: Please provide a sentence or two explaining this (not just a comment in your code sample).

Comment: I have edited the question. I am trying to build the program as a C program. It is a .C file

Comment: @Nipun Then why didn't you immediately roll back Wander Nauta's completely confusing edit, then? Please bring the question in proper shape, title, tags and all. Not to mention the fact that C just does **not** have references.

Comment: @Nipun the concept is the same... even the code, just remove the std::string and cout

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski thx, i'll delete the comment (never again c for me)

Comment: @Nipun: "It is a `.C` file" - which GCC takes to mean C++. Use `.c`, lower case, for C source.

Answer (score 2):

The definition and declaration each refer to a different function. More specifically, to a differnt overload of the same function name.

This:

```
void func(int, int*);
```

Declares a function taking an `int` and `int*`.

This:

```
void func(int a, int &p) { ... }
```

Declares and defines a function taking an `int` and `int&`. They're different functions. Calling code which sees both will call the appropriate one based on overload resolution as normal.

Comment: Since its build and run as a C program, I think overload will not come into picture

Comment: @Nipun `int &p` is not valid C syntax. If it passes compilation, it is being compiled as a C++ program.

Answer (score -1):

I couldn't understand clearly your question ,But I guess you are confused in mapping of parameters b/w function call and function definition, Especially pointers.
Use a lock and key concept to understand pointers. Suppose p is a pointer variable. &p is its address .

Now assume & is working as a lock . YOu want to access value p is pointing to ,So you need a key .Now I am giving you * key to open your & lock .
hence *(&p) will give you the value stored at address p was pointing to.